# How do you make a item in an item frame unable to be taken out?

Tags: minecraft-commands

I need to find out how to put something in an item frame but make it so I cant accidentally hit it out and have to put it back each time. How do you do this with commands in the version that bees came out?

Comment: Which game are you playing? MCJava, MCBE, MCCE, …?

Comment: In ```the version that bees came out``` so Java 1.15+.

Comment: Unfortunately, bees also exist in bedrock edition, so it could be either Java 1.15+ or Bedrock 1.14+.

Comment: Hi Kireagaming57, welcome to Arqade! We're more than happy to answer your question, but we need to know the platform (Bedrock/Java) you're on before doing so.